# Goland - generate type definition from JSON schema

Tags: goland

I have a both a example JSON file and a JSON schema. Is there any functionality in JetBrains GoLand IDE to generate the type definition given either of these files.

e.g. I have `data.json`:

```
{
    "title": "hello",
    "views": 45
}
```

and `data-schema.json`

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "views": {
            "type": "integer"
         }
    },
    "required": [
        "title",
       "views"
    ]
}
```

Is their functionality / extension to generate this type definition from the given files:

```golang
type Obj1 struct {
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Views int    `json:"views"`
}
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: @Krismorte No error, just wondering if Goland IDE had any features / extensions for generating struct definitions give a json file or json schema

Answer (score 1):

Marcin linked to a blog post how to generate structs from [json](/questions/tagged/json) in [goland](/questions/tagged/goland). Since the blog post is quite brief here are the steps in more detail.

1. Create a file (for example `order.go`) and add `package main` at the top
2. Left click in the file and in the context menu and select `Generate`
3. Select `Type from JSON`
4. Paste the json in the window
5. Optional: Refactor by introducing more types

Given this json

```json
{
  "messageid": 123,
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderid": 12, "buyerid": 45,
      "orderpositions": [
        {"orderposid":123, "qty":2, 
         "product": {"Id": 783, "name":"Foo", "price":"12.78"}},
        {"orderposid":124, "qty":4, 
         "product": {"Id": 784, "name":"Bar", "price":"2.10"}}
      ],
      "orderdate": "20240218"
    },
    {
      "orderid": 11, "buyerid": 27,
      "orderpositions": [
        {"orderposid":110, "qty":7, 
         "product": {"Id": 73, "name":"Yam", "price":"12.78"}},
        {"orderposid":111, "qty":9, 
         "product": {"Id": 34, "name":"Bam", "price":"72.00"}}
      ],
      "orderdate": "20240217"
     }
  ]
}
```

#### Step 2 Context Menu Generate

Within the file `order.go` open the context menu and click on `Generate`

[image: goland_go-file_context_menu]

#### Step 3 Type from JSON

In the `Generate`-Window select the option `Type from JSON`

[image: goland_go-file_generate_from_json]

#### Step 4 paste json

Enter the json object in the window and click the button `Generate`

[image: goland_go-file_paste_json]

#### Step 5 result

This should create a struct like this

```golang
package main

type T struct {
    Messageid int `json:"messageid"`
    Orders    []struct {
        Orderid        int `json:"orderid"`
        Buyerid        int `json:"buyerid"`
        Orderpositions []struct {
            Orderposid int `json:"orderposid"`
            Qty        int `json:"qty"`
            Product    struct {
                Id    int    `json:"Id"`
                Name  string `json:"name"`
                Price string `json:"price"`
            } `json:"product"`
        } `json:"orderpositions"`
        Orderdate string `json:"orderdate"`
    } `json:"orders"`
}
```

#### Refactor - introduce more types / structs

You can add more structs with the context menu option `Refactor` and pick `Introduce Type`

[image: Goland - Context Menu - Refactor - introduce new type]

For the Array you can pick either `struct { ...` or `[]struct { ...`. If you pick `struct { ...` then the JSON property `orders` will be an array of T like this: `Orders    []T`

[image: Goland - Context Menu - Refactor - introduce new type for array]

After the refactoring the file `order.go` looks like this

```golang
// orders.go
package main

type Product struct {
    Id    int    `json:"Id"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Price string `json:"price"`
}

type Orderposition struct {
    Orderposid int     `json:"orderposid"`
    Qty        int     `json:"qty"`
    Product    Product `json:"product"`
}

type Order struct {
    Orderid        int             `json:"orderid"`
    Buyerid        int             `json:"buyerid"`
    Orderpositions []Orderposition `json:"orderpositions"`
    Orderdate      string          `json:"orderdate"`
}

type T struct {
    Messageid int     `json:"messageid"`
    Orders    []Order `json:"orders"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible since version 2021.1-
https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2021/01/29/goland-2021-1-eap-begins/#work_with_json

```
Invoke Add key to tags on the struct or on any field in the struct via Alt+Enter. GoLand adds a tag to all fields in the struct with field names.
```